# Reference to object ( throught 3 classes)

Tags: java

I have a classes:

```
class A{
// represents the fields
}

class B{
A objA = new A();
// assigning a values to an object (objA) of class A
}

class C{
//I need this object (objA) with assigned values in the class B to calculations in class C 
}
```

How to pass (references?) to the class C? Or if there is a better way to thank you in advance for your help. Singleton is not an option.

I need to use object (objA) in class C.

Comment: If you just want to pass the *object* to another class, give it as a parameter to a method or set it as a property. Is there some problem with that?

Comment: If `C` needs an instance of `A`, why don't you just give it a class-level member of type `A` *exactly like you do in `B`*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expand your class **B** to something like:

```
public class B {
    private A objA = new A();

    public B() {
        objA.setA(4);
    }

    public A getObjA() {
        return objA;
    }
}
```

And class **C** should take a reference of **A** in its constructor like:

```
public class C {
    private A objA;

    public C(A objA) {
        this.objA = objA;
    }

    public A getObjA() {
        return objA;
    }
}
```

then in your main you can call:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    B bObj = new B();
    C cObj = new C(b.getObjA());

    System.out.println(cObj.getObjA().getA());
}
```

Now the object class **C**, `cObj` contains the same reference of class **A** object like the one in `bObj`

Comment: And how to use the methods of class A in the class C?

Comment: That's another question, short answer: by calling them! Inside the C class you have access to the private property `A a`. You can call any (public) method of `a` inside the `C` class. Be more specific if you want a more specific answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect your code, note that I have changed in Class C the `private A a;` to `private A objA;` in order not to mistake it with the property `int a;` of your A Class. I also added a getter `public A getObjA()`

Comment: Ok found it. You cannot call `objA.setA(4);` in that place in Class B. I have updated my answer and moved it to the main method. It should work now. If it doesn't please post the error not a simple "it doesnt work".

Comment: Returns the correct result but that's not the point here. In class B will be assigned values. And in C they have to be read.

Comment: That's exactly what is done here. `bObj.getObjA().setA(4);` line basically sets the `a` value to 4 inside the `objA` of `bObj` and then line `System.out.println(cObj.getObjA().getA());` reads the same `objA` reference but from the `cObj` and prints its value. Of course all this can be done inside Class B by making a constructor and assigning the `a = 4;` value there. But it is essentially the same thing, if you do not get it you need to refresh your Java and OOP skills.

Comment: For me, it would look like the class B constructor is where I will fetch values and attributed them to the object. A Class C I will perform calculations on the data contained in this object. So it's a little bit does not fit into this solution. You can not do anything?

Comment: Updated my answer in Class B added a constructor which sets the `a` property of the `objA` and removed the line `bObj.getObjA().setA(4);` from the main method. It should be what you look for.

Comment: So, can I do so that the class B will inherit the controller class and B class in the constructor accepts all values to the object and then covered in class C I can safely operate on these data?